# Crash in chrome with input [type = file] / Drag and drop javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, crash, drag

After hours and hours of searching an answer to my issue I finally decided to come over you.

**Here is the problem :**

I have a really simple page with an input = file. And a zone for showing the image loaded.

On the other side I have a Jquery/javascript script which load the file and put it in the div with onChange method.

**Two possibilities :** the user selects the image in file explorer and then click ok. Or he leaves the file window without loading any file by clicking cancel or close.

In this case everything is fine

**BUT** the user also can try to drag the file from the file window to the div. But I don't want him to do that and I know how to prevent this. (Look at the code below)

And it works, nothing enter in the div and the browser doesn't redirect on a new page.

It's not necessary for Firefox and internet Explorer, only chrome gives the possibility to drag from intern file explorer of the browser.

**Until this point, it's alright.**

**BUT** after dragging if the user try to leave the files window (by clicking cancel / close or in loading a new file) then chrome completely crash. (It doesn't crash everytime, but 1 time for 3 tests) and to this point : **the only possibility that remains is forcing the browser to close**

[**Bug in image**](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=897781crash.png)

And I really don't get why :/

I tried everything to get where the problem occurred with console.log .. but nothing happend before the crash. Not event the onchange() from the .js...

I also tried to do it with tiny file and the result is the same.

I think the bug is coming from Chrome browser but still, I can't let my website this way and I really need your help for this point.

**My idea are :**

- closing the file Window after the user tried to drag something but it seems impossible in javascript to close something we didn't open by ourself
- to make impossible to move or drag any file from the file window of the browser. Like it is in Firefox and Internet Explorer
- or just find the reason of the crash but it seems impossible to realize.. Console.log issue no message. It just crashes..

I hope you'll be able to deal with it better than me. I really need help here,

Regards

**The code :**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var loadFichier = $('#professionnal-icones-pictures-add'),
    contenerImages = $('#imagesPro');


  loadFichier.on('change', function(event) {


    console.log("change");
    event = event || window.event;


    var fichierLoad = loadFichier[0].files[0],
      output = document.getElementById('output1');


    if (output.src == "") {

      if (event.target.files[0]) {

        var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

        output.src = url;

      }

    }


  });



  window.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e = e || event;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);
  window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    e = e || event;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);



  contenerImages.on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  )
  contenerImages.on(
    'dragenter',
    function(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  )
  contenerImages.on(
    'drop',
    function(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {

          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();

        }
      }

    }
  );

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <link href="/sitePerso/vue/profil/style-profil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="professional-get-pictures">

    <div id="contener-selection">

      <div id="imagesPro">


        <div>
          <img id='output1' />
        </div>


      </div>


      <div id="contener-icones-pictures">

        <input id="professionnal-icones-pictures-add" type="file" accept="image/*">


      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="profiltest.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really surprised this issue led to any comment. This crash is still occuring on so many websites with chrome.

Still, I finally found one way to resolve this problem. It doesn't tell me why it was crashing on chrome (if one of you knew, I would be so glad to hear it). But it prevents the browser from crashing and it still stays comfortable for the user.

I added these two lines, in this way, the user really can't drag / drop anything from the file explorer :

```js
var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';
```

So this :

```js
 contenerImages.on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {


       e= e|| window.event;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();


    }
)

 $(window).on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {


       e= e|| window.event;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();


    }
)
```

Become this :

```js
 contenerImages.on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {


       e= e|| window.event;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';

    }
)

 $(window).on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {


       e= e|| window.event;

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

                var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.effectAllowed = dt.dropEffect = 'none';


    }
)
```

Perhaps someone found a better answer but I hope this post could help a lot of people.

The only problem with this is : it prevents the user from dragging from the file explorer as well (and not only from the file window of the browser). But I guess you'll find a way to deal with it.

I just make a summary of the problem for future readers : when I dragged file(s) from the internal file window of the browser (only chrome), and then tried to close it : it often brought this one to **crash**.

Have a good day everyone :)